# Name resolving issue

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, vlan, subnet, fqdn

I have a problem with my VoIP server name not resolving by voip.companyname.com

If I try to ping it from windows 7/w2k8 the request is not coming back unless I type FQDN which would by voip.companyname.com.domain.local

If I try to ping it from windowsxp/w2k3 I get a reply .

The VoIP is setup on VLAN/different subnet.

How can I make voip.companyname.com resolve on all the machines?

Comment: Please distinguish dns versus icmp echo request problem first.

Comment: ICMP echo response when using FQDN = Not an ICMP echo problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that companyname.com is in the DNS suffix search order list on the clients that need to resolve voip.companyname.com by single label.
2. If you are using WINS, ensure that the WINS settings are the same on all clients.

Edit: I'm sorry did you say your full domain name is truly `companyname.com.domain.local`? Wow. Well make sure companyname.com.domain.local is in your DNS suffix search order list then...

Comment: full domain name is domainname.local, voip.companyname.com is the voip server, in order to access it in windows7 machines I have to type voip.comanyname.com.domainname.local. DNS suffix seems to be set correctly, will check WINS setting.

Comment: Your DNS suffix search order should have two entries then. domainname.local first, companyname.com second. The domainname.local DNS server should have a conditional forwarder or a stub zone that points to companyname.com. voip.companyname.com should not be hosted within the domain.local zone.

Comment: DNS suffix had to be added to the dns suffix search list. Thanks for the help!